# Camel how to update multiple tables

Tags: apache-camel

I am in the process of developing a message router and I reached a point in which I need to update more than one database tables when processing a message.

Say the classical example when you receive an order message in a JMS queue that consist in order header information such as customer name, order date etc plus a list of ordered items such as item name, quantity, etc. In this case the order header information will go to an **ORDERS** table whereas the order items will go to an **ORDER_ITEMS** table.

```
<order-header customer="John Doe" date="2015-07-21" delivery-address="John's address">
    <order-item name="Camel in action" qty="2"/>
    <order-item name="Linux cook book" qty="1"/>
</order-header>
```

The simplest idea that came to my mind would be to route the message to a bean that will actually do the whole work such as inserting the order and retrieving the order id and then use that id to insert each order items. I am confident this will work but to me it does not look like a pure camel approach.

Another idea that came to my mind but more complex to implement would be to:

1. Get the message from the JMS endpoint
2. Enrich it with an order id using one of the multiple flavors of content enricher EIP
3. Use splitter EIP to split the above enriched message into one Order header and multiple Order items messages (and keeping order id in the exchange header)
4. Use a Content based router to route the Order header to an JDBC/SQL endpoint that knows how to insert records into the **ORDERS** table or to route am Order item to another JDBC/SQL endpoint that knows how to insert records into the **ORDER_ITEMS** table

Would this actually seem like a workable solution? My concern is that I would expect a foreign key constraint on the database side between **ORDER** and **ORDER_ITEMS** table and what it is going to happen if for whichever reason the Order item instance will get processed faster end will reach its JDBC/SQL endpoint before the Order header. Obviously that would mean trouble.

What is your opinion in general? Would this work as a viable approach.? Is there any way to address my sequencing concerns above.

Please note the order scenario is just an example to better explain my use case. In reality the message to process can be much more complex than a parent children template with more than two tables being both inserted into or updated.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Using Java classes like you describe is a pure camel approach. Camel is a Java library after-all. I do this regularly and it works perfectly. The JDBC/SQL components can also be used if they fit the bill.

Comment: Thanks Namphibian. Making use of the JDBC/SQL components and use all the out of the box infrastructure these components provide would be my ultimate goal. I updated my question with an alternative approach. I hope I'll get more inputs/ideas after this.

Comment: Julian yes this will work if you can give me a rough definition of the JMS message I can maybe help a little more,

Comment: Added a JMS message example. Please note I am not after how to parse that XML with camel I am after how to put everything together from the JMS end point to the DB ones. I need to know if my approach is workable and if things to watch out for. Thank again.